# Find nearest white pixel to a given pixel location openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I've got a binary image where I need to select the nearest white pixel to a given set of pixel coordinates.

For example, if I click on a pixel I need to have Python search for the nearest pixel with a value greater than 0 then return that pixel's coordinates.

Any thoughts?

I figured I should add what I've done so far.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('depth.png', 0) # reads image as grayscale
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 10, 50)

white_coords = np.argwhere(edges == 255) # finds all of the white pixel coordinates in the image and places them in a list.

# this is where I'm stuck
```

Comment: Simple approach, although perhaps not the most efficient. 1) [findNonZero](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190) 2) For each point, calculate distance to clicked coordinates. 3) Find point with minimum distance.

Comment: You could probably look into OpenCV's contours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- First use [`cv2.findNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190) to get a numpy array of coordinates of all the white pixels.
- Next, calculate distance from the clicked target point (Pythagoras theorem)
- Use [`numpy.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to find the position of the lowest distance.
- Return the coordinates of the corresponding nonzero pixel.

Example script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a test image
img = np.zeros((1024,1024), np.uint8)

# Fill it with some white pixels
img[10,10] = 255
img[20,1000] = 255
img[:,800:] = 255


TARGET = (255,255)


def find_nearest_white(img, target):
    nonzero = cv2.findNonZero(img)
    distances = np.sqrt((nonzero[:,:,0] - target[0]) ** 2 + (nonzero[:,:,1] - target[1]) ** 2)
    nearest_index = np.argmin(distances)
    return nonzero[nearest_index]

    
print find_nearest_white(img, TARGET)
```

Which prints:

```
[[10 10]]
```

and takes around 4ms to complete, since it takes advantage of optimized `cv2` and `numpy` functions.

---

Alternatively, you could go for a pure `numpy` solution, and as you have already attempted, use [`numpy.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) instead of `cv2.findNonZero`:

```
def find_nearest_white(img, target):
    nonzero = np.argwhere(img == 255)
    distances = np.sqrt((nonzero[:,0] - TARGET[0]) ** 2 + (nonzero[:,1] - TARGET[1]) ** 2)
    nearest_index = np.argmin(distances)
    return nonzero[nearest_index]
```

Which prints:

```
[10 10]
```

However, for me this is slightly slower, at around 9 ms per run.

Comment: This is great. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it was helpful. However, TARGET=(255,255) was misleading - why should it coincide with the intensity 255?

Comment: @KhelinaFedorchuk It's just an arbitrarily chosen coordinate to demonstrate how the algorithm works -- the "given pixel coordinate" for which we want to find the closest white point.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts, yes! Start looping from the given pixel, in first iteration check for all the pixels surrounding the given pixel, if a white pixel is not found, increment the distance by 1 and check if any pixel in the circumscribing perimeter of the given pixel is white, continue looping until you find a white pixel or go out of bounds.

Comment: IMHO this is more a of comment, than a proper answer, at least in the current state.

Comment: Sure, but with out stack trace or OP's coding efforts, this is an answer

Comment: Though not super efficient, this feels like decent a solution.

Comment: @Enigma Not sure what you need a stack trace for here, to be honest. Sure, the OP could have spent some more effort and took a shot at it himself, but the fact that they didn't doesn't really improve on the quality of this answer.

Comment: Bad answers to bad questions are useless. Either write a _decent_ answer regardless the question quality, or simply don't answer

Comment: @Miki I did not think it was a bad answer, that was the first that came to my mind, so answered. Again it's not the most efficient. Dan, I was meaning code, and when I answered, OP did not post any code.

Comment: Well, not efficient, really hard to code ( @Dan answer is just 4 lines, how much yours will be? ), no code at all.. also it won't work as expected...

Comment: @Enigma -- It is a valid idea, it doesn't need as much temporary memory, for short distances it could easily be faster even in Python. However, the implementation is non-trivial, so I'd definitely expect to see some working code example along with explanation and references (if relevant). I find it a very useful excercise to write a good quality answer that entails all that. And when I can't be bothered... well, that's what comments are for.

Comment: I could have commented - True, but I am unwilling to provide a working code example unless OP shows some effort by providing some code. Ready-made answers from SOF ruined me in my past. I know it helps but at one point I used to copy from here and paste it in my homework and submit without even reviewing. I could ask for the code in comments, but that just makes OP to look somewhere else, I thought an idea would make OP thinking again. Was totally thinking +vely, no offense intended whatsoever.

Comment: Oh, no offense taken :) I guess I just have a somewhat high bar as to what constitutes a good answer ;) What you describe are at least two good learning lessons -- experience is a good way to learn. I see those as "Don't write code you don't understand", and "Don't submit anything without proofreading". Heh, that reminds me... years ago, back in first year Uni, my friend came by after a night at the bar, and asked if he could look at my Java assignment. Feeling sorry, i gave it to him... little did I know he'd submit it whole, even with the copyright header unchanged...